# Adjacency of non-corner connecting spaces in Escape from Innsmouth

Tags: mansions-of-madness

We had an argument about an adjacency question in the board game **[Mansions of Madness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansions_of_Madness)**. In the "Escape from Innsmouth" scenario the upper left corner of the map looks like this:

[image]

The question is whether you can move from B to C directly, in other words whether those two spaces are adjacent. I argued that they are separated by a gray border (meaning a border between outdoor spaces), so they are adjacent spaces and a player or creature can move directly between them.

Everyone else in the group took the position that even though the curvy line did not match up to the corner with the library, that it was the intention of the game designers for it to be considered a mutual corner. Therefore, a player can only move between A and B or between A and C, and that it is not allowed to move directly between B and C.

Who is right?

Answer (score 1):

From the Rules Reference, regarding "Adjacent".

> Two spaces are adjacent if they share a border, a door, an impassable border, or a wall.

And from "Movement"

> When an investigator or monster moves a set number of spaces, it moves one space at a time, moving from one space to an adjacent space.

The tile sizes are standardized.  They only come in two sizes.  Square, as in your pier, or rectangular, like the alley.  The drawing of the borders is not done expecting somehow a squished down alley to fill only that part of the open space for A, and it's also not presented as somehow offset to only match A in the app (I've played through this too).  It may, in a different scenario or placement, have a door only bordering A or one of the Pier spaces instead, and in that situation would be different.

In your scenario and drawing however, A, B, and C are all adjacent to each other, and therefore B and C can be moved between directly.

Comment: I can see why someone might come to that conclusion though, and I doubt in my playthrough I handled it perfectly.  That notch is hard to notice with the mob running around.  I don't think it takes much from the game either way, but in this already difficult scenario, probably every point of movement counts.